# OpenSUSE 11.3 64-bit can't be Installed on AMD Athlon II X2 245

Tags: opensuse, central-processing-unit, 64-bit

I am not able to install OpenSUSE 11.3 **64-bit** on my AMD Athlon II X2 245. Whereas, **32-bit** version is already installed and running like charm.

The process starts fine, it loads the kernel and then it let me choose the language and keyboard layout. After that it tries to probe/setup things till 90%. And then is shows me the message couldn't create the `<some-path>` on the hard drive (some thing like that). I encountered similar error before, while trying to install 64-bit OpenSUSE to a 32-bit machine. But this one is 64-bit, I believe.

Any idea? Can BIOS be a issue? I mean is updating BIOS worth it?

In case all these information are required.

- Hard Disk: **SATA3 Hitachi**
- Graphics: **ATI Radeon HD4350**
- Mainboard: **ASUS M4N68T-M**
- Socket: **AM3**

Please let me know if any other information is required.

*Note: I have installed OpenSUSE 11.3 **64-bit using the same DVD** at office on Intel Core i7, 3 months ago.*

Comment: A listing of what kind of errors you're getting will be useful. Such as whether or not it boots (and what error messages you get). Or if it fails during the install process, where during the install process.

Comment: @sysadmin1138: Updated. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to make it work. What I did was,

- Installed Windows 7 64-bit, and then
- Installed OpenSUSE 11.3 64-bit

It got installed like charm. I don't know why it didn't complain about anything once I have Windows 7 64-bit installed on my machine. My guess is, may be installing Windows, made some changes in BIOS configuration, which enables OpenSUSE to recognise the 64-bitness of the machine. I don't know for sure why it did work this way. I can't think of anything else.